# Body full width background image

Tags: css

Is there any simple css trick to make body background width 100% and auto height? For example I have a 2100px wide picture and I want to scale it down to 1280px on 1280 wide resolution. P.S This applies strictly to body tag. Thanks!!!

Comment: `body { background-size: cover; }`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
body {
    background-size: 100% auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Tim's answer doesn't work for you, try:

```
body{
    background-size: cover;
}
```